# Vue .map is not a function on radio button group

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, pinia

I have a Vue app running a filter with Checkboxes and everything works fine for selecting multiple options. What I want to do is set it up to only allow one selection ie. Change input type to radio. The following function that worked with checkboxes throws this error in devtools console when changing the type to radio buttons...

`categoryParams.map is not a function`

Is this because it is now an Object and not an array? This is the function in question...

```
categories: []

let payload = {
              
    categories : this.prepareQueryStringFromSelectedCategories(this.categoriesSelected),
                  
};

prepareQueryStringFromSelectedCategories(categoryParams) {
    return categoryParams.map(element => element.slug);
}
```

What would the solution be to convert the checkbox array to allowing a radio button to be selected to filter?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this because it is now an Object and not an array? This is the function in question...

Yes. `.map()` is a [function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) on native Javascript arrays, nothing specific to Vue. According to the Vue [documentation](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/forms.html#radio-1), the bound variable in the view-model will contain the value of the selected item, so you should be able to access the property directly.

```js
prepareQueryStringFromSelectedCategories(categoryParams) {
    return categoryParams.slug;
}
```

Comment: Got it working thanks to your advice quaz77, 'return [categoryParams.slug];'